# How to extract a unique word list from a tab delimited textfile?

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk, sed

Given a tab-delimited file like this:

```
$ head train.txt 
The Fulton County Grand Jury said Friday an investigation of Atlanta's recent primary election produced `` no evidence '' that any irregularities took place .  AT NP-TL NN-TL JJ-TL NN-TL VBD NR AT NN IN NP$ JJ NN NN VBD `` AT NN '' CS DTI NNS VBD NN .
The jury further said in term-end presentments that the City Executive Committee , which had over-all charge of the election , `` deserves the praise and thanks of the City of Atlanta '' for the manner in which the election was conducted . AT NN RBR VBD IN NN NNS CS AT NN-TL JJ-TL NN-TL , WDT HVD JJ NN IN AT NN , `` VBZ AT NN CC NNS IN AT NN-TL IN-TL NP-TL '' IN AT NN IN WDT AT NN BEDZ VBN .
The September-October term jury had been charged by Fulton Superior Court Judge Durwood Pye to investigate reports of possible `` irregularities '' in the hard-fought primary which was won by Mayor-nominate Ivan Allen Jr. . AT NP NN NN HVD BEN VBN IN NP-TL JJ-TL NN-TL NN-TL NP NP TO VB NNS IN JJ `` NNS '' IN AT JJ NN WDT BEDZ VBN IN NN-TL NP NP NP .
`` Only a relative handful of such reports was received '' , the jury said , `` considering the widespread interest in the election , the number of voters and the size of this city '' .   `` RB AT JJ NN IN JJ NNS BEDZ VBN '' , AT NN VBD , `` IN AT JJ NN IN AT NN , AT NN IN NNS CC AT NN IN DT NN '' .
The jury said it did find that many of Georgia's registration and election laws `` are outmoded or inadequate and often ambiguous '' .  AT NN VBD PPS DOD VB CS AP IN NP$ NN CC NN NNS `` BER JJ CC JJ CC RB JJ '' .
It recommended that Fulton legislators act `` to have these laws studied and revised to the end of modernizing and improving them '' .  PPS VBD CS NP NNS VB `` TO HV DTS NNS VBN CC VBN IN AT NN IN VBG CC VBG PPO '' .
The grand jury commented on a number of other topics , among them the Atlanta and Fulton County purchasing departments which it said `` are well operated and follow generally accepted practices which inure to the best interest of both governments '' . AT JJ NN VBD IN AT NN IN AP NNS , IN PPO AT NP CC NP-TL NN-TL VBG NNS WDT PPS VBD `` BER QL VBN CC VB RB VBN NNS WDT VB IN AT JJT NN IN ABX NNS '' .
Merger proposed NN-HL VBN-HL
However , the jury said it believes `` these two offices should be combined to achieve greater efficiency and reduce the cost of administration '' .    WRB , AT NN VBD PPS VBZ `` DTS CD NNS MD BE VBN TO VB JJR NN CC VB AT NN IN NN '' .
The City Purchasing Department , the jury said , `` is lacking in experienced clerical personnel as a result of city personnel policies '' .    AT NN-TL VBG-TL NN-TL , AT NN VBD , `` BEZ VBG IN VBN JJ NNS CS AT NN IN NN NNS NNS '' .
```

Only the first column (delimited by tab) is important and I would like to extract the unique list of words (including punctuation) from the first column and output to a file. Assume that words are separated by space, i.e.:

```
$ head train.txt | cut -f1 
The Fulton County Grand Jury said Friday an investigation of Atlanta's recent primary election produced `` no evidence '' that any irregularities took place .
The jury further said in term-end presentments that the City Executive Committee , which had over-all charge of the election , `` deserves the praise and thanks of the City of Atlanta '' for the manner in which the election was conducted .
The September-October term jury had been charged by Fulton Superior Court Judge Durwood Pye to investigate reports of possible `` irregularities '' in the hard-fought primary which was won by Mayor-nominate Ivan Allen Jr. .
`` Only a relative handful of such reports was received '' , the jury said , `` considering the widespread interest in the election , the number of voters and the size of this city '' .
The jury said it did find that many of Georgia's registration and election laws `` are outmoded or inadequate and often ambiguous '' .
It recommended that Fulton legislators act `` to have these laws studied and revised to the end of modernizing and improving them '' .
The grand jury commented on a number of other topics , among them the Atlanta and Fulton County purchasing departments which it said `` are well operated and follow generally accepted practices which inure to the best interest of both governments '' .
Merger proposed
However , the jury said it believes `` these two offices should be combined to achieve greater efficiency and reduce the cost of administration '' .
The City Purchasing Department , the jury said , `` is lacking in experienced clerical personnel as a result of city personnel policies '' .

$ head train.txt | cut -f2 
AT NP-TL NN-TL JJ-TL NN-TL VBD NR AT NN IN NP$ JJ NN NN VBD `` AT NN '' CS DTI NNS VBD NN .
AT NN RBR VBD IN NN NNS CS AT NN-TL JJ-TL NN-TL , WDT HVD JJ NN IN AT NN , `` VBZ AT NN CC NNS IN AT NN-TL IN-TL NP-TL '' IN AT NN IN WDT AT NN BEDZ VBN .
AT NP NN NN HVD BEN VBN IN NP-TL JJ-TL NN-TL NN-TL NP NP TO VB NNS IN JJ `` NNS '' IN AT JJ NN WDT BEDZ VBN IN NN-TL NP NP NP .
`` RB AT JJ NN IN JJ NNS BEDZ VBN '' , AT NN VBD , `` IN AT JJ NN IN AT NN , AT NN IN NNS CC AT NN IN DT NN '' .
AT NN VBD PPS DOD VB CS AP IN NP$ NN CC NN NNS `` BER JJ CC JJ CC RB JJ '' .
PPS VBD CS NP NNS VB `` TO HV DTS NNS VBN CC VBN IN AT NN IN VBG CC VBG PPO '' .
AT JJ NN VBD IN AT NN IN AP NNS , IN PPO AT NP CC NP-TL NN-TL VBG NNS WDT PPS VBD `` BER QL VBN CC VB RB VBN NNS WDT VB IN AT JJT NN IN ABX NNS '' .
NN-HL VBN-HL
WRB , AT NN VBD PPS VBZ `` DTS CD NNS MD BE VBN TO VB JJR NN CC VB AT NN IN NN '' .
AT NN-TL VBG-TL NN-TL , AT NN VBD , `` BEZ VBG IN VBN JJ NNS CS AT NN IN NN NNS NNS '' .
```

I could do this:

```
$ python
>>> fout = open('word.dict', 'w')                                                                                                                                     
>>> fout.write('\n'.join(list(set(zip(*[line.split('\t')[0].lower().split() for line in open('train.txt')])[0]))))
>>> exit()
$ head word.dict
trenton
brevet
secondly
fig.
magnetic
doubts
monte
elisabeth
four
facilities
```

**But is there a way extract the same word list in shell/bash?**

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by "first column." Do you want every word? Or the first word of every newline? Or something else that I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cut -f1 file | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | sort -u
```

- `cut -f1` extracts the 1st tab-separated column
- `tr -s '[:space:]' '\n'` replaces each run of whitespace with a line break, effectively creating a list of words, each on its own line.
- `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` translates the lines to all-lowercase.
- `sort -u` sorts the resulting list of words with duplicates omitted (`-u`).

Comment: lowercase is missing =)

Comment: Actually the `sort -u -f` is rather good too but that way, we don't know which one gets picked in the unique. Thanks @mklement0

Comment: @alvas: Good point. The lowercasing requirement is buried in your Python code, however - I suggest you add it in prose too.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell where the tabs are in your posted sample input so this is untested but should do what you want:

```
awk '{sub(/\t.*/,""); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (!seen[tolower($i)]++) print $i}' file
```

or if you want all the output in lower case:

```
awk '{sub(/\t.*/,""); $0=tolower($0); for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if (!seen[$i]++) print $i}' file
```